# Mex - Passing and Receiving Variables

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm having trouble understanding how to pass and receive variables between matlab and mex. The main reason is that

The mex function's signature goes like this:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

Suppose inside the .cpp file I have a C++ function:

```
void foo(char stringInput , unsigned char arrayInput , int integerInput)
{interesting stuff}
```

And suppose I have all the inputs I need for foo in *plhs of the mex function.

how do I pass them to foo, and how to I return the results back to matlab?
I'm also not an expert in C++ syntax, so assume I know nothing =]

Thanks!

Comment: Best by example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html

Answer (score 0):

The mex function's signature you as u mentioned

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])

decodes the information passed from Matlab call to the mex function.

for example, if I have a mex function named 'add' and I want to call it from matlab using the command 
c = add(a,b);

In this case, my input variables 'a' and 'b' are stored in *prhs, (Pointer to Right Hand Side variables ) where as the variable 'c' is stored in *plhs, (Pointer to Left Hand Side variables ).

So, the point is, one needs to modify his *.cpp function depending on the way you want to call it from Matlab.

In your case, once you have copied all the variables passed from matlab in the mex function, you can call your foo function from the mex function like in usual way we do in only *.cpp files.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not a C++ expert, so  can you please specify how (syntax-wise) do I take the the variables, and send them back to matlab?